# multiple category by check at the same time

Tags: php, html

I would like to get more checkbox content into my database. It means that I have categories of php, java, html and css but I click on php and html, so it must be the two into in the same database that is within the database category.

It looks like this when I lie in the database:

```
$kategori = $_POST["kategori"];
```

How it looks when the user must select a category such as php and html to the database:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="kategori[]" value="<?php echo $tekst;?>"/>
<?php echo $tekst;?>
```

Right now when I put it into the database writes just "array" and nothing else even though I have selected two categories to the database.

How do I put multiple categories into the database same time?

Comment: `$_POST['kategori']` is an _array_ itself, so you must insert its values separately into your database.  `print_r($_POST['kategori'])` to see its structure.

Comment: it appears and writes like this `Array ([0] => asp [1] => java [2] => html)`

Comment: Read over [the many strategies listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+insert+array+into+database) for inserting array values.  There are several possible approaches to take,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

say for example you have 2 checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="kategori[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="kategori[]" value="2"/>
```

so when you submit the form in the submit page the data in the variable is $_POST["kategori"] is structure as:

```
Array([0] => 1
      [1] => 2
      ); //which you could see by executing the code print_r($_POST["kategori"]);
```

So in order to put it into the database you can change it into a comma seperated string and insert under a single field in the database table

```
$kategori = implode(",",$_POST["kategori"]); //which will give the output "1,2" when you do echo $kategori;
```

I hope this can be of some help

Answer (score 0):

You want each check to have an unique id, you submit the form to the back-end and then you can check the value of each checked check in the check-box by referring to the ids.